# How to change colour of histograms in seaborn pairplot (when using jupyter themes)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, themes, seaborn, jupyter

I'm not sure if it's just the theme and darktheme that I'm using but I can't seem to change the colours of the histogram on my pairplot.

Is there a way to change them as they are very dark looking or is this just because of the theme?

```
g = sns.pairplot(df)
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot,color='red')
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, color='green')
g.map_diag(plt.hist, color='blue')
```

[image: pairplot]

Answer (score 4):

Note that `sns.pairplot` creates a `PairGrid` and already draws the scatter dots and histogram. If you then draw your own histogram over it, thes probably don't coincide.  Therefore, it can help to replace `sns.pairplot` with `sns.PairGrid` giving empty subplots.

The following code has been tested with Seaborn 0.11.1 and matplotlib 3.4.1.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme('notebook', style='dark')
plt.style.use("dark_background")
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.PairGrid(df)
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot, color='crimson')
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, color='limegreen')
g.map_diag(plt.hist, color='skyblue')
plt.show()
```

[image: pairgrid change colors]